# Invalid operands to binary errors (have 'long unsigned int *' and 'int')

Tags: c, compiler-errors, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to set a bit at a given position but I keep getting an error can someone help with this?

This is my code:

```
int set_bit(unsigned long int *n, unsigned int index)
{
    long unsigned int value;

    value = n | (1 << index);
}
int main(void)
{
    int n;

    n = 1024;
    set_bit(&n, 5);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    n = 0;
    set_bit(&n, 10);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    n = 98;
    set_bit(&n, 0);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should dereference the pointer `n` to get the `unsigned long int` value.
- You should use `lu` prefix to the literal `1` to use `unsigned long` instead of `int` to prevent overflow in the shift operation.
- The return value of `set_bit` is not used and no `return` statement is used, so the return type should be `void`.
- `stdio.h` should be included to use `printf()`.

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void set_bit(unsigned long int *n, unsigned int index)
{
    *n = *n | (1lu << index);
}
int main(void)
{
    int n;

    n = 1024;
    set_bit(&n, 5);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    n = 0;
    set_bit(&n, 10);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    n = 98;
    set_bit(&n, 0);
    printf("%lu\n", n);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: this gives the answers i need but with a "passing argument 1 of 'set_bit' from incompatible pointer type" error when i compile with just gcc but doesnt when i compile with gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89. also, i cant change the function to a void function because i was given that specificfunction to work with.

Comment: @Jason I missed that the variable `n` in the function `main` has type `int`. The argument `n` of the function `set_bit` has type `unsigned long int*`, so the type of the variable `n` should be `unsigned long int`.

Comment: @Jason If the return type has to be `int`, it is safe to return something using `return` statement. Is what to return specified? If yes, return that. If no, `return 0;` after the assignment statement will work.

Comment: you were right. i rewrote the code and it worked without any errors. i probably wrote something wrong and i cant't place a finger on what i did wrong, but thank you!!

Comment: yeah the problem was it was supposed to be unsigned long int n in the main function, but i left it as int n thats why it was giving me the right answers and errors

Answer (score 0):

your set_bit function is expecting lu pointer (unsigned long int *n) while you are treating it in the function as a lu value (n | (1 << index)).

write it a bit differently - value= *n | (1 << index)

Comment: hi! i had a lead with thiss but the results werent exactly what i was supposd to get. i tried using *n = *n | (1lu << index); and that worked when i compiled with just gcc but not with gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89.

Comment: nvm for some reason it compild fine after i rewrote it. weird... but thank you so much

Comment: not sure what you were trying to do exactly, but it seems that you were passing the address of n (&n) to the set_bit function in order to alter it. however, the set_bit alters an automatic variable to the desired result and does nothing with the lu variable which you passed. thus, effectively you would never get the result.  I would not pass the address at all; rather pass n itself, and have set_bit return the desired value - e.g (in main) - n=set_bit(n); in set_bit(unsigned long n) - return n|(1lu << index). glad to help